# Hide "Dashboard" and "Home" button links in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

How can I configure the navigation bar from rails_admin to hide the "Home" and "Dashboard" buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [secondary navigation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/586309ac3a3ebcbcf42d329a9cfa6cab3364d1e6/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml#L3) doesn't have configuration options, but it does
define a CSS class for each of the "root actions", including `Dashboard`. You can use CSS to hide Dashboard:

```
.dashboard_root_link {
  display: none;
}
```

Consult the [Theming and customization wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Theming-and-customization#for-custom-theming-application-scoped-simply-override-these-files-in-your-app) for how to add `theming.css.scss` to your site. Make sure to [restart your server and clear your cache](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/738) for your new CSS.

The `Home` link only appears if you have a `root_path`, but you probably don't want to delete your root_path. The home link has no CSS class to target. If you're not using any of the secondary navigation links (actions, home, and _current_user), you could hide the enclosing class:

```
.nav.pull-right.root_links {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I've hidden all root_links in a sample rails_admin app I'm playing with if you want to take a look: https://github.com/slothbear/rails_admin_array_filter